# Whose is the IP address showed after command `ip -6 neigh`?

Tags: networking

```
xxx@xxx:~$ ip -6 neigh
fe80::fe48:efff:fe30:c7b dev eth0 lladdr fc:48:ef:30:0c:7b router REACHABLE
```

Whose IP is fe80::fe48:efff:fe30:c7b?
And whose MAC is fc:48:ef:30:0c:7b?

What does `lladdr` mean?

What would change if I configure it to `permanent`?